# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{x^n}{2n+1}}=\text{?} \ \ \ \ :x>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the limit below:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{x^n}{2n+1}}=\text{?} \ \ \ \ :x>0$$

My Try :
$$a_n:=\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{x^n}{2n+1}}\\ \ln a_n=\dfrac{1}{n}\ln \left(\dfrac{x^n}{2n+1} \right)\\ \ln a_n=\dfrac{1}{n}\left(n\ln x-\ln(2n+1)\right) \\ \ln  a_n=\ln x-\ln(\dfrac{2n+1}{n})  $$

So we have :

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{x^n}{2n+1}}=e^{\ln x-\ln 2}$$

Is it  right ?

Comment: I think you've mistaken multiplying the $ln$ by $\frac{1}{n}$ and dividing by $n$ inside of it...
What you should have on the final line is $ln(a_n)=ln(x)-\frac{ln(2n+1)}{n}$.

Comment: Note that $\exp(\ln(x))=x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler route. We have
$$
\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
=
\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}
$$
when both limits exist. For the sequence in question, the left limit is $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake when dividing by $n$. What you should have on the final line, is $$ln(a_n)=ln(x)-\frac{ln(2n+1)}{n}$$

The second term goes to 0 as $n\to +\infty$ ($n$ is much bigger than $ln(an+b)$), and the first one is constant. Therefore, $lim_n a_n=e^{ln(x)}=x$, and this for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{\frac{x^n}{2n+1}}&=x\lim_{n\to \infty }e^{-\frac1n \log(2n+1)}\\\\
&=xe^{-\color{blue}{\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac1n \log(2n+1)}}\\\\
&=xe^{-\color{blue}{0}}\\\\
&=x
\end{align}$$

Comment: why ?$$ \lim_{n\to \infty }\frac1n \log(2n+1)=0$$

Comment: You are correct.  And $e^0=1$.

Comment: @Almot1960 check my answer, $ln(an+b)$ is much smaller than $n$ at infinity, for all $a,b\geq 0$

Comment: @Almot1960 Yes.  In fact $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log(an^\alpha +b)}{n}=0$ for any $a, b, \alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

you are almost right the only problem is $\frac{1}{n} \ln (2n+1)$ is NOT equal to $\ln(\frac{2n+1}{n})$. But $\frac{1}{n}\ln(2n+1)\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$. Then
$$
\ln(a_n)=\ln(x) +\frac{1}{n}\ln(2n+1)\to \ln(x)
$$

Hence $a_n$ tends to $x$.